# Converting IP address to host name via DNS.GetHostEntry

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns

I am trying to get the hostname by passing in the ip address. I use the following code.

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.x.x").HostName
```

For some host the above code is returning correctly the hostname, but for few other host it throws an exception 'No Such host found'.

Could any one tell me why is this happening for some hosts?

I used the above code in an asp.net mvc application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all IP's are setup properly with a reverse DNS entry. These IP's are typically end consumers on lazy ISP's who don't provide `PTR` records for their clients. If there's no reverse entry, you can bet there's no forward entry either. As such, these hosts **have no hostname at all**, hence the exception. You'll need to catch this exception for these hosts and use something else such as their IP as an identifier.

Comment: @Bhaskar: That's the point though, not every IP *has* a hostname. Typically these cases are end-users on ISP's that are lazy with their reverse `PTR` records. What is the problem you are actually trying to solve? Almost all uses of a hostname could be equally satisfied by an IP address.

Comment: I am trying to find the client machine name from which the request is coming.

I am getting the client ip from the request header.

Comment: @Bhaskar: Then you're stuck with the problem I described above. These hosts have no hostname, their IP is your next best bet for an identifier.

Comment: why all IP's are **not** setup properly with a reverse DNS entry?

Is this done manually?

Comment: @Bhaskar DNS is manually setup, and sometimes blocked in the firewall. If it's an intranet, check with your system admin that you have a DNS Server and that it's accessible from the server that you are making this call. Try to run `ping -a 192.168.x.x` on the web server to make sure it can resolve the IP.

Comment: @Bhaskar Internal networks are another beast again. I'm not entirely sure how reverse lookups work on private networks. If you have an internal DNS server as part of your network then you could try setting up `PTR` records for all the clients on your network. Again, not quite sure how this works on private networks as they are a little different.

Comment: Thank you Michael and Matthew.

Comment: Hi I just need one more help.. When I tried ping -a 192.168.x.x from command line I got a successful reply.. I learnt that above thing is dns reverse lookup.

Does this means that there is an PTR record in DNS server.? and the code Dns.GetHostEntry(ip) should work?

Comment: @Bhaskar: If you get something like `Pinging stackoverflow.com [64.34.119.12] with 32 bytes of data:` as the first line, then yes. If you get something like `Pinging 64.34.119.12 [64.34.119.12] with 32 bytes of data:` then that means there's no `PTR` record setup.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `Dns.GetHostByAddress`, even though it complains about being depreciated. (VS2010 targeting 3.5)

`Dns.GetHostEntry` seems to throw an exception if a the target host is not reachable even if DNS knows the hostname. There doesn't seem to be any .NET way around this except for using depreciated methods. :\

(edit: though the above answer is also true - some machines just don't have hostnames. my answer is just if you know it should have a hostname but `GetHostEntry` doesn't work)